# SVG works fine on firefox but the its positioning changes on other browsers

Tags: html, css, svg

I have included a SVG for polygon and made necessary positioning.It works fine on firefox but the positioning changes on other browsers.I have attached the screenshots in both firefox and Chrome respectively.Why is this happening?[image: thisisthe one in firefox][image]

```css
  svg{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 17%;
      top: -23%;
    }
  .circle {
      background: #b7a3a3;
      height: 600px;
      width: 600px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="flex-auto flex items-center justify-center w-100">
            <div class="w-100">
              <svg class="w-100 white debug-grid mb4 db"viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-width="50"
                   id="js-svg">
                <polygon id="js-polygon" points="601.4282075197532,484.74767078498866 522.9616144951742,592.7476707849887 396,634 269.03838550482584,592.7476707849887 190.57179248024684,484.74767078498866 190.5717924802468,351.2523292150114 269.0383855048258,243.25232921501137 395.99999999999994,202 522.9616144951741,243.25232921501132 601.4282075197532,351.2523292150113" />
              </svg>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
```

Comment: It changes on Firefox too when you resize the window. One solution to your problem would be to center the polygon on the svg canvas and use `border-radius: 50%;` for the svg element. Yet another solution would be using an svg circle behind the poligon and center both.

Comment: Yup, and it's not even centered in the screen grab here. The svg has some extra space around the polygon making it difficult for you to position it correctly. I've modified the svg for my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got some issues stemming from the makeup of that svg. Your svg has a 461x468 unit polygon inside of a 1000x1000 unit viewbox and it isn't even centered.

It looks like what you want is a decagon centered inside of a circle. After normalizing your svg polygon the css gets a lot easier to deal with because you can just center it without using magic numbers.

To normalize the polygon, I took the points and subtracted the smallest x coordinate from all x coordinates, did the same for the y coordinates. Then add half of the stroke width to all coordinates. The viewbox then needs to fit the largest coordinates plus half of the stroke width.

I've absolutely positioned the svg inside of the circle to center it. The circle is set to height:0 and padding-top:100% to maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio.

If you want to use the bootstrap positioning and establish a 600px width, apply those styles to a parent element.

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
}

.circle {
  background: #b7a3a3;
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 461 486" stroke="#fff" fill="none" stroke-width="50" id="js-svg">
                <polygon id="js-polygon" points="435.856415039507,309.747670784988 
357.389822014928,417.747670784988 
230.428207519754,459 
103.466593024579,417.747670784988 
25,309.747670784988 
25,176.252329215011 
103.466593024579,68.252329215011 
230.428207519753,27 
357.389822014928,68.252329215011 
435.856415039507,176.252329215011" />
              </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he needs to do a better svg, he is job will be easier

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much.It's my first time using SVG so I don't have that much knowledge.